# String HTML in android

Tags: android, textview, html

I have a string html , and in it i cant change font size & font type just,  I can change font color. how can use special font type & size in it .

```
<![CDATA[
       <font color=\"red\" size=20 ><b>Title</b></font>
        <p>  text </p>
        ]]>
```

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are asking. The data in the CDATA section are just characters, notions like font or size don't make sense here.

Comment: how can i define font type(face) in it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the color, size and typeface like this:

```
<![CDATA[
  <font color='red' size='20' face='serif'>title</font>
  <p>text</p>
]]>
```